# How to show that $\int_0^\infty (\partial_t \phi(x_t, t)+\left\langle \dot x_t, \nabla_x \phi(x_t, t)\right\rangle) \mathrm d t=0$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, elliptic-equations, divergence-operator, gradient-flows

Let $u :\mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R$ be smooth and $v := \nabla u$ its gradient. We fix $x_0$ and let $x_t$ be the solution of $\dot x_t = v(x_t)$ started from $x_0$. Let $\rho_t := \delta_{x_t}$ for all $t \ge 0$. Then @leo said in his [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/438871/what-does-the-continuity-equation-s-nabla-cdot-rho-nabla-u-mean?noredirect=1#comment1131828_438871) that

> $\rho_t$ solves the continuity equation $\partial_t\rho_t+\nabla\cdot(\rho_t v)$ in the sense of distribution, i.e.,
> $$
> \int_0^\infty \int_{\mathbb R^d} \left(\partial_t \phi(x, t)+\left\langle v(x), \nabla_x \phi(x, t)\right\rangle\right) \mathrm d \rho_t(x) \mathrm d t=0 \quad \forall \phi \in \mathcal C^\infty_c(\mathbb R^d \times (0, \infty)).
> $$

**My understanding** It follows from $\rho_t := \delta_{x_t}$ that
$$
\begin{align}
&\int_{\mathbb R^d} \left(\partial_t \phi(x, t)+\left\langle v(x), \nabla_x \phi(x, t)\right\rangle\right) \mathrm d \rho_t(x) \\
={} &\partial_t \phi(x_t, t)+\left\langle v(x_t), \nabla_x \phi(x_t, t)\right\rangle \\
={} &\partial_t \phi(x_t, t)+\left\langle \dot x_t, \nabla_x \phi(x_t, t)\right\rangle.
\end{align}
$$

Then we need to show that
$$
\int_0^\infty (\partial_t \phi(x_t, t)+\left\langle \dot x_t, \nabla_x \phi(x_t, t)\right\rangle) \mathrm d t=0.
$$

> Could you elaborate on how to finish the proof?

Comment: The integrand looks a lot like $\frac{d\phi(x_t,t)}{dt}$, doesn't it?

Comment: @StiftungWarentest Thank you so much. So the integral becomes
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d \varepsilon} \phi(x(\varepsilon), \varepsilon) \bigg\lvert_{\varepsilon= t} \mathrm dt.
$$
Could you elaborate how it is $0$?